# port windows 8 apps store library

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

is there a way to port a library developed for windows 8 app store(for c# and Xaml)  so that  it can be  used in windows 8 apps store developed in HTML5/Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just adding it as a reference? Do you get errors if you do?

I see others have done this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/e890e461-a6fc-4396-8a27-57ed090998a5/ "You need to set the Output Type to WinMD in the properties."

Comment: Great, I was happily suprised to see you could mix languages this way. :)